# How to redirect php file outside of the folder location?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

Hello how do you redirect a page outside of the 'Model' folder because all my html files are outside of it. I want to redirect my page using this location

```
http://localhost/laurence/FirstDayTraining/index.html
```

Example:
I have a php folder inside the 'Model' folder name `login.php` so in order to redirect it to the index.html, I have to use `header("Location: laurence/firstdaytraining/index.html");` but when I click enter this will be displayed

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
```

and the location is going to this path

```
http://localhost/laurence/FirstDayTraining/Model/index.html
```

Please help, how to redirect my page in this

```
http://localhost/laurence/FirstDayTraining/index.html
```

but not this

```
http://localhost/laurence/FirstDayTraining/Model/index.html
```

Comment: http://localhost/laurence/FirstDayTraining/index.html 
this link show correct ? if not then use absolute path

Comment: yes but when I submit my form it will redirect to the `http://localhost/laurence/FirstDayTraining/Model/index.html` my index html is not found in the `Model` folder sir, it is outside the `Model` folder. Whats the syntax for the correct path location?

Comment: just show your redirect code.......

Comment: try something like this: `header("Location: ../index.html");`. I added two dots in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    header('Location: ../index.html');
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: @Carl answer below is a one liner that works fine. I don't see any reasons why you were checking for the transfer protocol type which you ended up not using in your example.

Answer (score 3):

Based from your info, Try something like this:

```
header("Location: ../index.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

~/webpath/laurence/FirstDayTraining/index.html

Try this ? And change webpath to your website folder.
~/ means your user folder if your on linux.